# How do I base an outlook rule on the number of "To:" addresses?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

I would like to create an Outlook rule that stops me from sending out emails that have more than ten email addresses in the "To:" line. Is this even possible? I'm using Outlook 2010 on Windows 7 64-bit.

My reasoning:
I send out a distribution letter to a large number of addresses. I usually send this email to myself with the distribution list addresses in the "BCC:" line. Every once in a while I mess up and accidentally put the distribution list addresses on the "To:" line instead. This is a problem because then each email recipient will see all the addresses on the list. I want Outlook to stop me from doing this, or at least warn me before I send it out.

I also welcome suggestions on how to get around this problem.

Answer (score 4):

There's no built-in way to do this, but you can achieve it with a macro.

Steps<sup>1</sup>:

1. In Outlook, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open **Microsoft Visual Basic**.
2. On the left side of the screen, expand the folder called **Microsoft Office Outlook** and double-click **ThisOutlookSession**.<sup>2</sup>
3. In the window **VbaProject.OTM - TheOutlookSession**, select **Application** in the left and **ItemSend** in the right drop-down menu.<sup>2</sup>
4. Replace the code that apperaed in the window's body by the following:

   ```
   Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
       Dim Recipients As Integer
       Dim Start As Integer
       Dim Last As Integer
       Recipients = 1
       Do
           Start = Last + 1
           Last = InStr(Start, Item.To, ";")
           If Last = 0 Then Exit Do
           Recipients = Recipients + 1
       Loop
       If (Recipients > 10) Then
           Cancel = (MsgBox(Str(Recipients) & " recipients in To field.", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel)
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save.
6. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to return to Outlook.

This macro will display a warning if there are more than 10 recipients in the **To** field (based on the number of semicolons used to delimit the recipients). You can click `OK` to dismiss the warning or `Cancel` to abort.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm using Outlook 2007 (in Spanish). I hope Outlook 2010 is similar.

<sup>2</sup>
[image: screenshot]

<sup>3</sup>
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with Outlook.  While you can use third-party solutions to limit it (i.e., Thunderbird), you lose the functionality of Outlook itself.  This is actually a great question, though, and I would love to see Microsoft provide a little better control over what you can and can't send out!

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you for answering.

Comment: No problem; I can't count the number of times I have done exactly what you're trying to prevent yourself from doing.  It's too bad the rules aren't more flexible!

Answer (score 0):

I took Sudo's answer and made it count the recipients in CC and BCC as well, just In case anyone wants it:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Recipients As Integer
    Dim Start As Integer
    Dim Last As Integer
    Dim RecipientFields As String
    Recipients = 1

    RecipientFields = Item.To

    If (Item.CC <> "") Then
        RecipientFields = RecipientFields + ";" + Item.CC
    End If

    If (Item.BCC <> "") Then
        RecipientFields = RecipientFields + ";" + Item.BCC
    End If

    Do
        Start = Last + 1
        Last = InStr(Start, RecipientFields, ";")
        If Last = 0 Then Exit Do
        Recipients = Recipients + 1
    Loop

    If (Recipients > 6) Then
        Cancel = (MsgBox("You have " & Str(Recipients) & " recipients in To/CC/BCC fields.  Click OK to send.", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel)
    End If
End Sub
```