# Outlook 2010 Rule: Move message if greater than 5 recipients

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter

The only time I get emails with 5+ recipients is when the office gossip is going around. I would love to make a rule/filter to move any incoming message with more than 5 recipients into a junk folder.

Is that possible with Outlook 2010? I could not find anything like that in the default rules, wasn't sure if you could VB the rule. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: With VBA it should be very much possible. [Here's](http://superuser.com/a/445926/138343) a macro that counts the number of recipients in a mail being sent (Application_ItemSend() event). You should be able to tweak it to run when a mail is received, using either the NewMailEx() or Items.ItemAdd() events as detailed [here](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the VBA script using resources from StackOverflow and SuperUser if anyone is interested.

This script takes all incoming emails and counts the recipients in the `To:` field,if recipient count is greater than 5, marks it as read, and moves is to a `Gossip` folder.

There is also a secondary condition to check if subject contains `CVS` (we get updates from our concurrent version system which has 10 recipients) and move is to the appropriate folder.

```
Sub moveOfficeGossip(item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim strNames As String, i As Integer, j As Integer, cvs As String
    Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    j = 1
    cvs = "CVS"
    strNames = item.To
    Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    For i = 1 To Len(strNames)
        If Mid(strNames, i, 1) = ";" Then j = j + 1
    Next i

    If (j >= 5) Then
        If InStr(UCase(item.subject), cvs) Then
            Set olDestFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Filtered").Folders("CVS")
            item.Move olDestFolder
        Else
            Set olDestFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Filtered").Folders("Gossip")
            item.UnRead = False
            item.Move olDestFolder
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I apologize if this is not in the most formal format and I know that it can be organized a bit better, but this was my first attempt at using any Visual Basic syntax.